# Querying nested objects in Django for OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a data structure that looks like this (simplified version)

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    c = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

Now, my question is, what kind of query do I have to perform so that I find all objects b of class B such that b.c.a = 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be `b = B.objects.filter(c__a=1)`.